# how to change the label from the horizontal scroller

Tags: ios, horizontal-scrolling

how to change the label from the horizontal scroller ?
I have a page with players image and i want to change the label for each image
please help me i can't find answer for this! 
I'am sorry about my english...

```
@interface KLViewController ()


@end

@implementation KLViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:10/255.0 green:37/255.0 blue:70/255.0 alpha:1]];

//Initialize the informtion to feed the control
NSString* plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"SectionData"
                                                      ofType: @"plist"];
// Build the array from the plist
NSArray* controlData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
self.horizontalSelect = [[KLHorizontalSelect alloc] initWithFrame: self.view.bounds];
[self.horizontalSelect setTableData: controlData];
[self.horizontalSelect setDelegate:self];
//Customize the initially selected index - Note section is redundant but should always be 0
[self.horizontalSelect setCurrentIndex:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:4 inSection:0]];

//Add the view as a subview
[self.view addSubview: self.horizontalSelect];

}


-(void) horizontalSelect:(id)horizontalSelect didSelectCell:(KLHorizontalSelectCell*)    cell {
    NSLog(@"Selected Cell: %@", cell.label.text);   


}

- (void)dealloc {
    [_players release];
    [super dealloc];
}
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [self setPlayers:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
@end
```

Comment: you want to change frame or text of label.?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have already solved.
You must change the label's text into the classes of KLHorizontalSelect. 
In the code that you have posted inside the plistPath string there is your answer. You can see that the label's name and the image's name file are into the "SectionData.plist" file.
Open this file and change what you want.